# Quartz, How to start a job after another job finishes?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I'd like to use quartz for a project, but it seems to be missing some functionality. What I need is very simple, to fire another job after one finishes execution. This ideally would be done with a stored trigger, but quartz only considers time-based triggers, and no other kind. I'm looking for some kind of a job dependency system for quartz.

In reality there should be lots of triggers, such as other jobs finishing, files being modified, database tables being updated, etc.

Here's a job that waits for 5 seconds:

```
public class JobA implements Job, JobListener {

public static final String LISTENER_NAME = "JobA";

public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {

    System.out.println("Job A, Waiting for 5 seconds");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5L * 1000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done waiting");
}

public String getName() {
    return LISTENER_NAME;
}

public void jobExecutionVetoed(JobExecutionContext context) {
    //TODO
}

public void jobToBeExecuted(JobExecutionContext context) {
    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
    System.out.println("Job : " + jobName + " is going to start...");

}

public void jobWasExecuted(JobExecutionContext context,
        JobExecutionException jobException) {
    //      System.out.println("jobWasExecuted");

    String jobName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
    System.out.println("Job : " + jobName + " is finished...");

    if (!jobException.getMessage().equals("")) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown by: " + jobName
                + " Exception: " + jobException.getMessage());
    }

    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("JobA", "group1");
    try {
        context.getScheduler().triggerJob(jobKey);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

The context.getScheduler().triggerJob(jobKey) line simply doesn't work. I've tried adding full jobs, recursive jobs, and can't seem to get anything to work. How can I get another job to fire while using this listener?

Comment: Have you looked into http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/listeners/JobChainingJobListener.html ?

Comment: hrm. I will take a look.